# Show that the odd prime divisors of $n^2+n+1$ are of form $6k+1$ (exclude 3)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the odd prime divisors of $n^2+n+1$ are of form $6k+1$ (exclude 3)

---

I have started like below:
$n^2+n+1\equiv 0 \pmod {p_i}$
$(n+1)^2\equiv n \pmod {p_i}$

Any hints/help on how to proceed from here ?

Comment: Yeah I'll update, 3 excluded

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look at what it means for $\left[(2n+1)^2\mod{p}\right]$ if $p\mid n^2+n+1$.

Without quadratic reciprocity, you will need to use:

$$n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$$

Then show that any $p>3$ which divides $n^2+n+1$ does not divide $n-1$. So $n$ is a non-trivial third root of unity modulo $p$ if $p\mid n^2+n+1$ and $p>3$. When does $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ have a third root of unity other than $1$?

Comment: $$4n^2 + 4n+1  \equiv  4(n^2+n)+1\equiv  -3 \pmod p$$ ?

Comment: Exactly! What do you know about quadratic residues?

Comment: interesting, but i don't see yet how to use this to my advantage

Comment: I am familiar with linear congruences and chinese remainder theorem. Quadratic reciprocity law is next chapter

Comment: Edited with a hint if you don't have quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is to *complete the square*:
$$n^2+n+1=\left(n+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34.$$
If $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $n^2+n+1$, then...

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: The approach I suggested uses some facts about quadratic residues which I presume you haven't learned yet. You may want (I recommend you) to take another look to this as soon as you have seen quadratic reciprocity. Meanwhile, you can check out Thomas Andrews' answer which shows a way around using some facts about the _multiplicative order_ modulo primes.

Comment: Umm...I'm not the OP. I learned quadratic reciprocity 30 years ago! And with Thomas Andrews' answer to help, I see the connection.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that ;) Anyway it's what I would have said to the op...

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be an odd prime divisor of $n^2+n+1$

Then   $n^2+n+1  \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
\implies n^3-1  \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
\implies n^3  \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

So $ord_pn=3$ (obvious!) and so $3|\phi(p)=p-1$

Note that $p-1$ is even. So $2|p-1$.

Since $gcd(2, 3)=1$, so $6|p-1\implies p-1=6k, k\in\Bbb{Z}\implies p=6k+1$